# Discord.py edited messages logger malfunction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This code allows edited messages to be logged in another channel on a discord server, however sometimes it takes the sending of GIFs and counts it as an edited message. How do I fix that even though I thought I told it to ignore embeds?

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, message_before, message_after):     
    if message_before.author == self.client.user: #Checks to see if the author of the edited message wasn't BenBot.
        return
    elif message_before.author.bot == True: #Checks to see if the author of the edited messages wasn't a bot
        return
    if len(message_after.embeds)>1: #Checks to see if the message hasn't been edited with an embed.
        return
    now = datetime.now() #Grabs the current time
    current_time=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") #Formats the current time into a readable form.
    current_date=now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #Formats the current date into a readable form.
    edit_embed=discord.Embed(title = f"Message Edited", description= f'**User:** <@{message_before.author.id}>\n**Channel:** <#{message_before.channel.id}>\n**Server:** {message_before.guild}\n**Message (Before Edit):** \n{message_before.content}\n**Message (After Edit):** \n{message_after.content}\n\n[Jump to This Message]({message_before.jump_url})', color=0x00ff00) 
    edit_embed.set_footer(text=f"Message ID: {message_before.id}\nDate: {current_date} • Time: {current_time}") 
    edit_embed.set_author(name =f"{message_before.author}", icon_url=f"{message_before.author.avatar_url}") 
    archive_edit=self.client.get_channel(789929258184474675) #Grabs the ID of the Edited Messages Channel where the archive is to be stored.
    try:
        edit_embed.set_image(url=message_after.attachments[0].proxy_url)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    await archive_edit.send(embed=edit_embed) #Sends the edited message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I had that issue too, When I sent a link, discord would add an embed to that link, and that would count as an edit. However, the contents would still remain the same. So I fixed it with this condition:

```py
if message_before.content == message_after.content:
    return
```

So, your event would look like this:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, message_before, message_after):     
    if message_before.author == self.client.user: # Checks to see if the author of the edited message wasn't BenBot.
        return
    elif message_before.author.bot == True: # Checks to see if the author of the edited messages wasn't a bot
        return
    elif message_before.content == message_after.content: # Checks to see if there is an actual edit
        return

    now = datetime.now() # Grabs the current time
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # Formats the current time into a readable form.
    current_date = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") # Formats the current date into a readable form.

    edit_embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Message Edited", description = f'**User:** <@{message_before.author.id}>\n**Channel:** <#{message_before.channel.id}>\n**Server:** {message_before.guild}\n**Message (Before Edit):** \n{message_before.content}\n**Message (After Edit):** \n{message_after.content}\n\n[Jump to This Message]({message_before.jump_url})', color = 0x00ff00) 
    edit_embed.set_footer(text = f"Message ID: {message_before.id}\nDate: {current_date} • Time: {current_time}") 
    edit_embed.set_author(name = f"{message_before.author}", icon_url = f"{message_before.author.avatar_url}") 

    archive_edit = self.client.get_channel(789929258184474675) # Grabs the ID of the Edited Messages Channel where the archive is to be stored.

    try:
        edit_embed.set_image(url = message_after.attachments[0].proxy_url)
    except IndexError:
        pass

    await archive_edit.send(embed = edit_embed) #Sends the edited message
```